# mysql select contain range of information

Tags: mysql, select, filtering, imdb

I'm working on a project dealing with the IMDB database.
I've searched around but haven't come across anything that would help.

I need to filter out movies before 31 December 1983.

However the table structure is set up with the release_date column being VARCHAR and the values are something like: USA:31 December 1983.

```
movie_id         release_date
283192           USA:31 December 1983
```

EDIT: I was looking through some of the records and some of the dates only include the year.

Does anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this? Or somewhere to look?

Thank you.

Comment: Try converting the column to date via `STR_TO_DATE('USA:%e %M %Y')`. If the "USA:" part is dynamic, you'll need to do some string manipulation to extract just the date part first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it to a date using `str_to_date()`, but you need to get the part after the `:`, so:

```
select str_to_date(substring_index(release_date, ':', -1), '%d %M %Y')
```

Comment: This gave me a list of NULL values when I ran it. I ran exactly:

`SELECT str_to_date(substring_index(`release_date`, ':', -1), '%d/%M/%Y') FROM `release_dates`;`

Didn't give me any errors, either.

Comment: @SkyKnight . . . Are you sure that is the format of the ate?

Comment: Yeah. I tried this, `REPLACE INTO release_dates (release_date) SELECT str_to_date(substring_index(release_date, ':', -1), '%d/%m/%y') FROM release_dates;` and it gave me this error: ERROR 1411 (HY000): Incorrect datetime value: '22 January 2006' for function str_to_date

Comment: Interesting.  Your date format pattern is not the format patter in my answer.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you so much! I discovered, though, that some of the records are NULL due to some of the records only having the year. Do you know of a way to fix it?

Comment: @SkyKnight . . . You should ask another question with appropriate sample data and desired results.